# Switch off the g (global) modifier in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

The `g (global)` modifier is `on` by default in `preg_replace` PHP, how can it be switched off ?

If I do a `preg_replace(/n/,'',$string);` it will replace all occurrences of `n` but I want to replace only the first occurrence of `n`. How should I do it?

Comment: see the php doc, preg_replace has a limit parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the fourth parameter for [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace). From the documentation:

> **limit** — The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).

```
preg_replace('/n/', '', $string, 1);
```

But for something simple as this, a regex is overkill. A simple [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) should suffice:

```
$string = str_replace('n', '', $string, 1);
```

Comment: wow man , never knew about this fourth parameter, i m new to php

Comment: @aelor: It's easy to overlook things. When in doubt, always check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/preface.php).